# Powershell split by '_' return empty

Tags: powershell

So i have folder with several files:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem "myPath")
```

I can see via the debugger that `$files` contains several items and i want to take the first:

```
$files[0] = "123_this.is.string"
```

And i want to split in by `'_'` and take `123`

```
$splitted = $files[0] -split "_"
```

So here i can see that `$splitted` is empty.

Any suggestions why this strange behavior ?

Comment: this works fine for me, please provide a minimal verifiable example

Comment: I believe, you should use `Name` property value to split. Your `$file[0]` should contain an object with a bunch of properties, and you can't split objects. Try `$files[0].Name -Split '_'`.

Comment: `$files[0] -split "_"` and `$files[0].Name -split "_"` should give the same result.

Answer (score 6):

$files[0] isn't a string but a FileSystemInfo Object.

```
$files[0].getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

So to get it work you have to use the split function to the filename of the file which is a string.

```
$files[0].name.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     String                                 System.Object
```

With this it should work:

```
$files[0].name.split("_")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$files[0].ToString().split("_")
```